# Empty space instead of a cell in html table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-table

I am getting an empty space instead of a cell in html table.
[Click this for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twLoF.png)

Actually I am using MVC with razor engine to generate the html with lot of c# code.Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated.I would like to post the code but it's a client project ,hence I need to maintain confidentiality.

Comment: unless you provide some sample code. it is difficult to guess what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Perhaps you code modify your code so that any confidential stuff is hidden, but you can still demonstrate what you are trying to do?  Otherwise it will be very hard for anyone to help you - we'll all just be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the colspan attribute of td :

```
<td colspan="2" style = "text-align:center;">
```

Comment: Thank you for help .As I said I am not supposed to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code this is a problem with HTML/CSS.  A couple things to check:

1. Cell Spacing/Cell Padding (for each cell on CSS, etc)
2. Check to see if you have an extra space.
3. Check the length of a cell (and if it's if a div, etc. for widths)
4. Try doing this (remove the carrier return between the text and closing td tag).

   `<td`>This is a cell.`</td`>
5. Check font sizes in this row for all cells.
6. Check text, cell heights.  Looks like all the other rows have  and the one with the space doesn't.  Could be effected by  height.

Pretty much I'm shooting in the dark here without seeing the code/html/css.

HTH